# How to update Rails version to 6.0.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

Yesterday I updated my Ruby version to 2.6.5 with rbenv, but today I had a problem when I wanted to update Rails to 6.0.2.1.
It didn't work well.

This is what I have:

```
echo $PATH                       
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:./bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/paulinedussart/.rbenv/shims:/Users/paulinedussart/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/paulinedussart/.rvm/bin
```

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

```
which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

I did:

```
gem install rails
```

I got:

```
Successfully installed rails-6.0.2.1
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.2.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

then `rbenv rehash`.

When I ran `which rails` or  `which -a rails` I got:

```
/usr/bin/rails
```

To check if everything was ok I ran `rails --version` but the result was:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
    $ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

but I did not do that.

Somewhere I saw this instruction

```
ls `rbenv prefix`/bin
```

to check if Rails was there but it doesn't appear:

```
bundle  bundler erb     gem     irb     rake    rdoc    ri      ruby
```

Finally, when I run `gem list rails` I get:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rails (6.0.2.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
```

I obviously closed the terminal at a different step of the config but without success.
I'm sure there is a problem with folders but I don't know how to fix this to put the `gem rails` in the correct one.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Run `gem env` and `rbenv versions` and copy their output and paste it into your question, formatting it appropriately. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags as we can tell what changed and when. How did you install `rbenv`? Did you use `sudo` at any time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Switch to Ruby 2.6.5:

```
rbenv global 2.6.5
```

Install the Bundler gem:

```
gem install bundler
```

Install Rails:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: This. I assume it's a new ruby, which needs all the gens reinstalled

Comment: Thank you ! But finally I just run `rbenv exec gem install rails` then `rbenv rehash`and it's worked ! :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `rbenv rehash`.

Also you can check "[Rails is not currently installed on this system - High Sierra #1106](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1106)".

I had the same issue and I refered to this issue and found we don't need:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
```

You just need:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

if you install it via Homebrew.

Comment: Hi @ken Sanchez and thank you ! I already saw this issue but don't work with me. This is what I have in my bash_profile :  
`if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`